# Problems with is_user_logged_in() | Function in WP

Tags: login

I use this code to display the user profile in WordPress:

```
   <?php
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     if ( ($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) {
       echo '<div class="omid-header-proimg">'.get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 64 ).'</div>';
       echo '<div class="omid-header-protext">'.esc_html( $current_user->display_name ).'</div>';
       echo '<div class="omid-logpanel"><a href="https://test.com/panel">panel</a></div>';
    }
    }
   ?>
```

But when I want to use the following code for when the user is not logged in, the site will not be loaded. where is the problem from?

```
    <?php
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     if ( ($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) {
       echo '<div class="omid-header-proimg">'.get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 64 ).'</div>';
       echo '<div class="omid-header-protext">'.esc_html( $current_user->display_name ).'</div>';
       echo '<div class="omid-logpanel"><a href="https://test.com/panel">panel</a></div>';
    }
  }
  else {
    echo '<div class="omid-header-proimg"><img src="'. bloginfo('template_url') .'/images/omid-nonsignin.png"></div>'
    echo '<div class="omid-logpanel"><a href="https://test.com/panel">login</a></div>'
  }
?>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `bloginfo` doesn't return the template url, it outputs the termplate URL, if you're inseting it into a string, use `get_bloginfo` instead. But in this case there is a much better function `get_template_directory_uri()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last lines are missing semi-colons:

```
  echo '<div class="omid-header-proimg"><img src="'. bloginfo('template_url') .'/images/omid-nonsignin.png"></div>';
  echo '<div class="omid-logpanel"><a href="https://test.com/panel">login</a></div>';
```